# Can we exclude some type from our interface?

Tags: typescript, types

I want to get all types that have toString. I have made an interface like this.

```js
interface Stringable {
    toString(): string
}
```

It should accept all primitives (except `null | undefined | symbol`) and exclude all `Map | Object | Promise | etc` (`toString !== Object.prototype.toString && toString !== Array.prototype.toString`)

Is it possible to check this at the type level?

Answer (score 0):

1. Everything extends Object so you can't exclude it.
2. Because of `Object.prototype.toString()`, everything is stringable
3. Because it doesn't know TypeScript try union, like `number | boolean | string | bigint | ...`

I also had this interface in my projects but I just stopped do that and solved this:

```
function userInput(input: string | number | Date | boolean) {
   const string = input.toString()
   // ...
}
```